# Selenium test can find drop-down in debug mode but not in run (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea

I have written an automated test using Selenium in Java.

If I insert a relevant break point and run the test in debug mode (IntelliJ) the test works fine. When I try to run the test it fails at the point where it is not able to locate the desired element from a drop-down list.

Code snippet:

```
driver.waitForElementPresent(PageElement.byXpath(XPATH_TEMPLATE_TEAM_OPTION, XPATH_TEMPLATE_TEAM_DESCRIPTION, team));
driver.selectFromVisibleText(SELECT_TEAM, team);
```

N.B. Analogous code is being used elsewhere in my project and is working fine.

Error I am getting:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: Sounds like a timing problem. If you could post a [mcve], perhaps we could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use expicity wait instead of waitForElementPresent: The following code wait for the PageElement for 10 seconds, but you can increase or decrease based on your page load time.

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(PageElement.byXpath(XPATH_TEMPLATE_TEAM_OPTION, XPATH_TEMPLATE_TEAM_DESCRIPTION, team)));
driver.selectFromVisibleText(SELECT_TEAM, team);
```